# Images on UITableView NOT WORKING

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

After successfully getting the text to work on my `UITableView`, I still have not got the images working. It seems that the `LogoURL` array is blank on `UITableViewCellsForRow`, here is my code.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) MSTable *table;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *items;



@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *MainTableView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // create the activity indicator in the main queue
    self.MainTableView.hidden = YES;

    UIActivityIndicatorView *ac = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                                   initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [self.view addSubview:ac];
    [ac startAnimating];






    self.client = [MSClient clientWithApplicationURLString:@"https://outnight-mobile.azure-mobile.net/" applicationKey:@"okYeRGfBagYrsbkaqWIRObeDtktjkF10"];
    self.table = [self.client tableWithName:@"notifications"];
    self.rowitems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    MSQuery *query = [self.table query];
    query.fetchLimit = 3;
    [query readWithCompletion:^(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error)
                                {

                                    self.rowitems = [items mutableCopy];
                                    [self.MainTableView reloadData];
                                    self.MainTableView.hidden = YES;



                                    int a;
                                    for (a = 0; a < 3; a++)
                                    {
                                        NSDictionary *apt = [self.rowitems objectAtIndex:a];
                                        NSLog(@"%@", apt[@"barID"]);
                                        NSDictionary *barIDDictionary = @{ @"myParam": apt[@"barID"]};
                                        self.client = [MSClient clientWithApplicationURLString:@"https://outnight-mobile.azure-mobile.net/" applicationKey:@"okYeRGfBagYrsbkaqWIRObeDtktjkF10"];
                                        [self.client invokeAPI:@"photos" body:barIDDictionary HTTPMethod:@"POST" parameters:nil headers:nil completion:^(id result, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {


                                            if (error) {
                                                        NSLog(@"Error %@", error );
                                            }
                                            else        {
                                                NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [result objectForKey:@"rows"]];
                                                NSString *stringWithoutbracketsend = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
                                                NSString *stringWithoutbracketsfront = [stringWithoutbracketsend stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
                                                NSString *completion = [stringWithoutbracketsfront stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
                                                NSString *newStr = [completion substringFromIndex:1];
                                                NSString *finalstring = [newStr substringToIndex:newStr.length-(newStr.length>0)];
                                                [self.logoURL addObject:finalstring];
                                                NSLog(@"%@",finalstring);
                                                [self.MainTableView reloadData];
                                                self.MainTableView.hidden = NO;

                                            }

                                            }];
                                  }

                                }];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [self.rowitems count];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
  NSDictionary *stress = [self.rowitems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.textLabel.text = stress[@"content"];

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.logoURL objectAtIndex:(1)]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greybox40.png"]];
            NSLog(@"%@", [self.logoURL objectAtIndex:(1)]);
            break;

        case 1:
            [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greybox40.png"]];
            break;

        case 2:
            [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greybox40.png"]];
            break;

    }


    return cell;
}



@end
```

As you can see on the first case statement, I have tried to see if I can see the array contents and I cannot. Any help would be fab - I am sure its to do with where I put my reload table but again I am unsure.

Comment: Where you initialising `self.logoURL`?

Comment: and it should be of type strong

Comment: in the .h file in the same place as the array for the text

Comment: it is strong and nonatomic

Comment: u should first create the mutable array before adding stuff to it.self.logoArray =[NSMutableArray array];

Comment: why you need placeholderImage with the same name? It not true when you need load multiple images

Comment: I am happy to remove the placeholder image but it makes no difference at the moment!

Comment: I have [alloc init] the logoArray and now I am getting the error when it tries to read the array , it says '-0 bound to array' so its blank when it yes to CellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Does `logoUrlArray` have element in index:1?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    NSDictionary *stress = [self.rowitems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = stress[@"content"];

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@"]]]];
            NSLog(@"%@", [self.logoURL objectAtIndex:(1)]);
            break;

        case 1:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@"]]]];
            break;

        case 2:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@"]]]];
            break;

    }


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Oterwise try AsyncImageview.,